# SAS EG How to do a conditional sum for an unique column combination?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to sum value-column values that match a code-column value, for each unique combination of person and Time. The concept should be simple, but I just can't seem to manage...:

INPUT TABLE:

```
Time   |  Person  |   Value|  Code
_____________________________________
1 | A | 10 | Z1    
1 | A | 11 | Z2    
1 | A | 12 | Z3    
1 | A | 13 | Z4    
1 | A | 20 | Z5    
2 | A | 23 | Z1    
2 | A | 21 | Z2    
2 | A | 33 | Z3    
2 | A | 32 | Z4    
2 | A | 37 | Z5    
1 | B | 38 | Z1    
1 | B | 43 | Z2    
1 | B | 12 | Z3    
1 | B | 13 | Z4    
1 | B | 10 | Z5    
2 | B | 10 | Z1    
2 | B | 11 | Z2    
2 | B | 22 | Z3    
2 | B | 23 | Z4    
2 | B | 10 | Z5
```

etc.................. for many more people and times and codes.

I want to sum the Value column  for the `code-column` =`Z1` and `Z3`. And for `Code` = `Z2`, `Z4` and `Z5` etc. for each person at each time with no structure in the codes I sum over.

So the output would be something like this:

```
Time   |  Person  |   NewValue|  NewCode
_____________________________________
1 | A | 22 | "Z1+Z3"
1 | A | 43 | "Z2+Z4+Z5"
1 | B | 50 | "Z1+Z3"
1 | B | 66 | "Z2+Z4+Z5"
2 | A | 56 | "Z1+Z3"
2 | A | 90 | "Z2+Z4+Z5"
2 | B | 32 | "Z1+Z3"
2 | B | 44 | "Z2+Z4+Z5"
```

etc..................

I hope the concept is clear - I want to sum values based on the code column, for each unique person-time combination. There is no logic in which codes I want to sum over. (`Z2+Z4`, or `Z10+Z11+Z12+Z17`, and `Z16+Z20` etc. Codes could be used more than once as well. I just have a manual ever-changing list of which codes to sum over.)

I've tried a number of things so far, like:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE output AS
    SELECT value FROM input
    WHERE code = "Z1" + value WHERE code = "Z3"
    AND time=time AND person=person;
QUIT;
```

Though this is syntax-gibberish, it does illustrate what I am trying.

Comment: It's also not really clear to me at least. Can you have multiple codes per person, or only 2? Are the codes specific to person or in general across all people?

Comment: Z2 + Z3, Z4 + Z5...well that kinda implies we should have Z5 + Z6. But apparently , you are following a different pattern here...what's the pattern?

Comment: I cannot understand the logic you use to go from the first table to the second.  I think you haven't given us enough information to help you.

Comment: Have edited the question. While asking this I was suddenly rushed, leading to an incomprehensible problem - my apologies.

Comment: @Jerros instead of adding your answer as a preface to the question, suggest you add it as an answer and accept it. This is acceptable on S.O., and makes life easier for folks searching the archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The easiest and quickest way to do this is to first transpose the INPUT table doing a "Group analysis by" Person and Time, using Code as "new column names" and Value as "transpose variable".

Next you can just sum over w/e codes you want using something like:

```
%_eg_conditional_dropds(WORK.OUTPUT); 

PROC SQL;
       CREATE TABLE WORK.OUTPUT(label="OUTPUTname") AS 
       SELECT t1.Person, 
              t1.Time, 
                (SUM(t1.'Column Z1'n,t1.'Column Z3'n)) AS 'NewCode 1'n, 
                (SUM(t1.'Column Z2'n,t1.'Column Z4'n,t1.'Column Z5'n)) AS 'NewCode2'n
    QUIT;
```

This can even be expanded and simplified by using arithmetic instead of the "sum" command like, like:

```
/*Instead of*/
(SUM(t1.'Column Z1'n,t1.'Column Z3'n)) AS 'NewCode 1'n,
/*do stuff like:*/
t1.'Column Z1'n + t1.'Column Z3'n - (t1.'Column Z3'n - t1.'Column Z5'n) AS 'NewCode 1'n,
/*etc.*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are always manually creating new values, you can keep a list of what you would like to sum in an external file.

```
File: Combination.xlsx

Combination
Z1 Z2 Z3
Z1 Z4
Z2 Z5
...
```

Next, create a program that reads through those combinations and saves them to a macro variable.  You can filter for each combination using SQL.

```
proc import file='C:\Location\Combination.xlsx'
            out=_Import_Combination
            dbms=xlsx
            replace;
run;
```

The below will create a new variable that turns your combination into the correct syntax for an `IN()` statement. e.g. `"Z1","Z3","Z5"`

```
data Combination;
   set _Import_Combination;

   do i = 1 to countw(Combination);
       if(i = 1) then Filter = quote(scan(Combination, i) );
           else Filter = catt(Filter, ",", quote(scan(Combination, i) ) );
   end;
run;
```

Next, save the combination names and filters to a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
      select Combination
           , Filter
           , count(*)
      into :combos separated by '|',
           :filter separated by '|',
           :total_combos
      from Combination
      ;
quit;
```

Finally, loop through all of the combinations that you need.  You can filter for each combination using SQL.

```
%macro countAllCombos;
    %do i = 1 %to &total_combos;
        %let current_combo = %scan(&combos, &i, |);
        %let current_filter = %scan(%bquote(&filter), &i, |);

        proc sql noprint;
             create table %sysfunc(tranwrd(&current_combo, %bquote( ), _) ) as
                   select Time
                        , Person
                        , NewCode
                        , sum(Value) as Total_Value
                   from input
                   where code IN(&current_filter)
                   group by Time, Person
              ;
        quit;
   %end;
%mend;

%countAllCombos;
```

The final output will be tables stored in the WORK library named:

```
Z1_Z2_Z3
Z1_Z4
Z2_Z5
...
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the elaborate response. I'll try your solution first thing on Monday.

Comment: Also, the final column doesn't have to represent the codes that were summed. (eg if the values are Z6+Z4+Z1, the name doesnt have to be "Z1_Z4_Z6" or something). I assign custom new names to the summed ones.

Comment: Ah, the first codeblock (the Excel format example)  should be all in one cell, got it. And in the third codeblock I can't loop over "i" since it errors that that's a column name. I now loop over Z, creating a column Z containing the number of codes summed over +1.

Comment: Errors in the %countallcombos macro: ERROR: Macro function %SCAN has too many arguments.  The excess arguments will be ignored.
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       "352" 
ERROR: Argument 2 to macro function %SCAN is not a number.
ERROR: The macro COUNTALLCOMBOS will stop executing.

Comment: Updated. Give it a try now. I added `%bquote` around `&filter` in the `%scan` function. `&filter` stores the text: `"Z1", "Z3" | "Z5", "Z8"`, and required a macro quoting function.

Comment: Sorry, it's still erroring... but you did inspire me to another solution. See the second edit in the original question for how I solved it.